# Format String issue incorrect format specifier

Tags: c++11, mfc

My String looks like :

```
std::wstring replacePattern = L";FOLD PTP %1 Vel=100 % PDAT%2";
```

I am expecting to put values on it :

```
CString replaceString;    
replaceString.Format(replacePattern.c_str(), posData.m_posName, posData.m_posName)
```

Run Time :Error :

```
 Expression: ("Incorrect format specifier", 0)
```

The value can be string or integer.
Please suggest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MFC/ATL's [CStringT::Format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/18he3sk6.aspx) doesn't support positional format specifiers, so `%1`, `%2`, and so on aren't legal type fields. You'll have to use `%d` (for integers) or `%s` for strings. If you need a percent sign in your format string, you need to escape it using `%%` (see [printf Type Field Characters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hf4y5e3w.aspx)).

Your pattern should look like

```
std::wstring replacePattern = L";FOLD PTP %d Vel=100 %% PDAT%d";
```

or

```
std::wstring replacePattern = L";FOLD PTP %s Vel=100 %% PDAT%s";
```

depending on the data type of `posData.m_posName`.

Comment: i needed to use % and the escape string by extra % worked for me with the %s & %d as needed. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5):

If you need to use %1 and %2 then consider using the [FormatMessage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/041zd9kb.aspx) **CString** member instead. And, as mentioned, use %% if you want a % character.

But using **FormatMessage** you can do what you want.

So it would be something like:

```
std::wstring replacePattern = L";FOLD PTP %1% Vel=100 %% PDAT%2!d!";

CString replaceString;    
replaceString.FormatMessage(replacePattern.c_str(), posData.m_posName, posData.m_posName)
```

If you want something like a integer you use:

```
%1!d!
```

Just change the number to indicate the variable you are using.

If you want something like a CString you use:

```
%1%
```

The help topic above provides more details. So, whilst you can amend your format string so that **CString::Format** will work, it does tie down the order of your values. But if due to localization you need ability to have values in different order, consider using **CString::FormatMessage** instead.

Comment: You linked to the Visual Studio 6 version of the MFC CString class. The current ATL/MFC documentation is available at [CStringT::FormatMessage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/041zd9kb.aspx).

Comment: @IInspectable Thank you. I was trying to locate a newer web page. Shall I revise my answer to use the newer link?

Comment: I'd suggest that you link to the current documentation. The link in your answer really only refers to the MFC CString implementation that ships with Visual Studio 6 (and may no longer apply). Plus, all links on that page to other information are dead by now.

Comment: @IInspectable Done! :)